# Why another cell in the listview also change color when I just set one cell to be changed?

Tags: android, listview

I got a long listview, I tried to change the color in a particular cell, e.g position == 0, it works fine. But when I scroll down the list, another cell that out of the screen before is also change. any idea? thanks for the help

```
public class CheckWinNoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Context context;
private String[] values;
TextView tvMain;




public CheckWinNoAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super(context, R.layout.list_draw, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_draw, parent, false);
    }

    tvMain = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chk_main);
    tvMain.setText(values[position]);



    if(position ==0){
        tvMain.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    }

    return convertView;
```

Comment: also definitely worth watching http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html

Answer (score 2):

You are recycling views by reusing `convertView`, you have to always set the color in `getView()`, like

```
if (position == 0) {
    tvMain.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
} else {
    // set color back to original color
    tvMain.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
}
```

See http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/

Comment: hi biegleux, thanks for the anwser. just wondering how can i stop the listview for recycling?

Comment: Don't stop it! Your listview will be slow by not reusing the view, if you remove (convertView == null) check and always call convertView = inflater.inflate(), you will inflate new view each time an item in listview is visible, it is quite slow operation and may slow down scrolling, use the approch described above, not recycling view is really a bad practice, see also http://stackoverflow.com/q/3817628/1300995

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figure out by myself now, instead of ding  if (convertView == null) {}
I use

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {



    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_draw, parent, false);
        TextView tvMain = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.chk_main);
return rowView;
```

so not recycling views, just in the rowView.

Comment: This is wrong. Users of your app will encounter performance issues by not recycling your views.